# Why Edit.GoToDefinition in Visual studio 2008 opens the object browser?

Tags: visual-studio

1 week ago, when I hit F12 (Edit.GoToDefinition command) in visual studio, it opened me the class definition in a metadata file.
Now when I hit F12, visual studio send me to the class definition in the object browser.

Do you know how to modify this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you are using a language which does not support this behavior.  The default behavior for most languages and Edit.GoToDefinition is to bring up the object browser as you've indicated.  This is true for VB.Net, C++, etc ... The only language which supports the generation of MetaData is C#.

Which language are you using?